# In QBO's v3 API (IPP), do all shipping lines map to the same account?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

When I query an invoice that contains a shipping line, I get:

```
{
    "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail", 
    "Amount": 25.0, 
    "SalesItemLineDetail": {
        "ItemRef": {
            "value": "SHIPPING_ITEM_ID"
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like in the UI, in Advanced Settings, a shipping account can be selected by a user. What's not immediately clear is if I go in and change it, will all previous transactions that used shipping change to that account too? Or will only new shipping transactions from that point forward hit the new account? That, obviously, will impact the usefulness of the item ID provided by the Invoice query response.

Thank you!

As a reference, a Read on the company's Preferences object includes this information:

```
"AllowShipping": true,
"DefaultShippingAccount": "277",
```

I guess it's not immediately clear to me if the item that maps to this income account is generated by the system or was created by the user, but it probably doesn't matter. The real question is whether changes to it propagate to prior transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I tested this in one of my company files- I see that shipping line in txns does not refer to any accountref and there is no way of knowing to which account this amount is posted.
However, when I changed the default ship account to something else then Company pref query result shows the new account details.
I will have to check with the QBO product team on this one to find our if all existing txns are also impacted or not.

EDIT: Existing txns are not impacted by changing shipping account.